Hydraulic Pump Life
It is common knowledge that hydraulic oil breaks down >140 °F, and for every 18 °F above that it breaks down twice as fast.
Is there a similar rule of thumb for how fast a hydraulic pump wears when the oil temperature gets too cold?

Temperature control is why most hydraulic systems have associated cooling...

https://www.fluidpowerworld.com/hydraulic-seals-battle-extreme-cold/

The problems are mostly to do with internal seals not doing their job. There are hydraulic fluid tank heaters available. Often, they run off engine coolant, so you just use a conventional block heater and circulate the engine coolant to the other tanks. Cycling the hydraulic system under no load for several minutes after the engine is up to temperature will help under arctic conditions. (I used to spec equipment for northern Alaska and Antarctica when I was in the Air Force 40 years ago.)  https://www.petersoncat.com/sites/cat/files/downloads/Cat%20ArcticTDTO.pdf

No. While there is some standardization on the fluid used, the pumps are diverse. Pistons, rotors, pistons on rotors... There might exist a rule for a specific pump, but the only general rules like that are that greater use and loads lead to more wear.
Rule of thumb in physics/chemistry is that it takes energy to break bonds. Making more energy available to break the metal bonds will lead to more broken bonds.
Parts, metal in particular, are often designed with 200k cycles in mind (with some factor of safety on top); if you load and unload for that many times and it does not break, it becomes difficult to predict how many more cycles it will last. Was your pump designed for such? What factor of safety on top of that was used? (There are tradeoffs such as weight that come with higher factors of safety)

I am using a variable volume piston pump.  The pump manufacturer recommends operating between 5°C-60°C.

Best you can probably do other than ask the manufacturer is to look at waste energy at your various conditions. Temperature won't be the only factor and without knowing what component the waste is increasing in from the conditions, it's still guesswork.
